# Constructor Calls For Class inheriting from vector Confusion

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector, constructor

In the following code, I am creating a Vector class that inherits from the standard vector class. I am confused as to why in main, my Vector object doesn't call the derived class constructor when I include the following line

```
using vector<T>::vector;
```

but when I don't include it, it calls my derived class constructor as expected. What is the reason for this? I haven't been able to replicate the problem with toy code, so that would be very much appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Vector : public vector<T>
{   
    vector <T> x;
    //using vector<T>::vector;
    public:
    Vector(vector <T> x)
    {
        this->x = x;
        for (auto i: this->x)
            cout << i << " ";
    }
    
};

int main() {
    Vector <int> x({1,2,3,4,5});
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Re: "inherits from the standard vector class" -- that's generally a bad idea. `std::vector` is not designed to serve as a base class.

Answer (score 1):

You pass `{1,2,3,4,5}` (which is not a `std::vector`) as the argument to `Vector`. Since `std::vector` provides [a better match](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) for that type, and you asked to reuse its constructors, it is constructed directly.

If you pass a `std::vector<int>{1,2,3,4,5}` instead, [your constructor gets called](https://godbolt.org/z/7dEG3ehdb).

Note also, that your example code constructs 2 `std::vectors` as part of `Vector` (the inherited one and the member `x`) and [`using namespace std` is considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).